# Cannot set property href undefined - iFrame not created before javascript fires from html onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, href

I've inherited a very old php application. There is an issue running in Chrome / Edge where  a second (child) dropdown does not show. This works in IE where the user selects a populated value from the first list and then the second dropdown appears with child values.

I have tracked it - I think - to the fact that the reference in the javascript does not yet exist. The error message in the console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined
    at loadStuff (app.js:193)
```

Does my analysis look correct and is there a way to work around this without much re-writing. I did try getElementById() in the javascript as shown and it looks like it returns a value.

From the code snippets below it looks like "the_iframe" is not defined by the time the javascript app.js tries to set `frames['the_iframe'].location.href= "....etc..."`

All suggestions welcome! I have been considering a button to fire the population of the child records etc. as this is very much a legacy app and I am very much not a PHP/Javascript/HTML person.

FYI: I've anonymised a lot of the function calls and variables and cut out as much noise as I could.

forma.php

```
<form method="post" action="php_file_here.php?show_prev=yes" onSubmit="addThings()">

<table width="64%" border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" align="center">

    <tr align="left" valign="top">
        <th class="purple_cell" colspan="2">
            Instruction to choose here
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select id="site_selector" name="location" OnChange="loadStuff(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select from list</option>


                <?php

                // Loop through things here and populate dropdown
                // Lines removed for brevity
                    print($my_option);

                }

                ?>


                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- stuff removed -->  
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" colspan="2">
            <iframe id="the_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="" width="600" height="24">

            </iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- stuff removed -->

</table>
```

app.js

```
function loadStuff(an_id, another_id) {
    const element = document.getElementById("the_iframe"); //This has a value in chrome debugger  I added it to see

    frames['the_iframe'].location.href = "../dir_here/another_php_file_here.php?an_id="+an_id+"&another_id="+another_id;

    proceed_text.innerHTML = "Now Choose more things which will be in this dropdown";

    return true;

}
```

Comment: When you do `console.log(frames['the_iframe'])`, what do you see?

Comment: Iframe doesn't have an `href` attribute, it has a `src` attribute.

Comment: why not `frames['the_iframe'].src = "..."` as stated in all documentation?

Comment: Or if you want to access the `address.href` use:  `frames['the_iframe'].contentWindow.location.href = "..."`

Comment: @MisterJojo `frames['the_iframe']` returns a window object, not an iframe element.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, That's new to me! 

Comment: @Teemu - with console.log I get: ```<iframe id="the_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="" width="600" height="24">``` which expands under the  ```#document``` node to show ```<html>  <head></head> <body> </body> </iframe>```

Comment: @Teemu so what? , it is the same object as `document.querySelector('#the_iframe')` and it will always have a `scr` property to property to fill in

Comment: @MisterJojo - I believe I tried the src property this morning after reading around but had the same issue. My server is gone for the day but I will try again first thing to see. The reason that href is used - I don't know. I didn't write this in 2005 :)